# ion2-calendar, Error when showing months from a selected year

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, calendar

My goal is to show all the days of a selected year. From January to December, so that the user can pick or view the dates on that year. For that, I'm using [ion2-calendar](https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar).

So far I have this:

```
  date: Date = new Date(); 
  async openCalendar() {

const options: CalendarModalOptions = {
  title: 'Plano de Férias',
  //defaultDate: new Date(2019,0,1),
  pickMode: 'multi',
  color: 'primary',     
  weekdays : ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S'],
  weekStart : 1,
  canBackwardsSelected: false,
  closeLabel : 'Fechar',
  doneLabel : 'OK',
  disableWeeks : [0,6],
  from : new Date(2019,0,1),
  to : new Date(2019,11,31)
};

const myCalendar = await this.modalCtrl.create({
  component: CalendarModal,
  componentProps: { options },
});

myCalendar.present();

const event: any = await myCalendar.onDidDismiss();
const { data: date, role } = event;

if (role === 'done') {
  this.date = date.dateObj;
}
console.log(date);
console.log('role', role);}
```

With this code, which the `from:new Date(2019,0,1), to:new Date(2019,11,31)` means that the start date is the first of january and the last is the 31st of December of 2019, the month December doesn't show, either do the January of 2020, but Feb. and so on do.
[image: From January to December]

If I change the code to `from:new Date(2019,1,1), to:new Date(2019,11,31)`, The Output is what I want, but there's no January month.
[image: From Feb to December]

I don't know if it is a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong, but so far I did not find an appropriate answer. If you know some plugin for ionic4, that looks like this, share it. Thank you for your time in advance.

**SOLVED**
Solution can be found in [here](https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar/issues/273#issuecomment-574965319).

Comment: Fixed, please refer here: https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar/issues/273#issuecomment-574965319

Comment: @Yodism, thanks for noticing me! I'll check it!